# Сборка ELF с использованием libelf

Tags: c, elf

Всем привет! Не получается собрать исполняемый файл ELF с помощью библиотеки libelf для

```
Linux ws-3 4.10.0-38-generic #42~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 10 16:32:20 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

При выполнении сгенерированного исполняемого файла падает ошибка

```c
$ ./test
bash: ./test: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, какие ошибки вы видите в коде примера и как их правильно исправить

1. Код

```
#include <err.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <libelf.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sysexits.h>
#include <unistd.h>

unsigned char code[] = {
    0xB8, 0x3C, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, // mov rax, 60
    0xBF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, // mov rdi, 0
    0x0F, 0x05                    // syscall
};

#define LOADADDR 0x08048000

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int fd;
    Elf *e;
    Elf_Scn *scn;
    Elf_Data *data;
    Elf64_Ehdr *ehdr;
    Elf64_Phdr *phdr;
    Elf64_Shdr *shdr;

    if (argc != 2)
    {
        errx(EX_USAGE, "usage: %s filename\n", argv[0]);
    }

    if (elf_version(EV_CURRENT) == EV_NONE)
    {
        errx(EX_SOFTWARE, "elf_version is ev_none, wtf? %s\n", elf_errmsg(-1));
    }

    if ((fd = open(argv[1], O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, 0777)) < 0)
    {
        errx(EX_OSERR, "open failed: %s\n", elf_errmsg(-1));
    }

    if ((e = elf_begin(fd, ELF_C_WRITE, NULL)) == NULL)
    {
        errx(EX_SOFTWARE, "elf_begin failed: %s\n", elf_errmsg(-1));
    }

    if ((ehdr = elf64_newehdr(e)) == NULL)
    {
        errx(EX_SOFTWARE, "elf64_newehdr failed: %s\n", elf_errmsg(-1));
    }

    ehdr->e_ident[EI_DATA] = ELFDATA2MSB;
    ehdr->e_ident[EI_CLASS] = ELFCLASS32;
    ehdr->e_machine = EM_X86_64;
    ehdr->e_type = ET_EXEC;

    size_t ehdrsz = elf64_fsize(ELF_T_EHDR, 1, EV_CURRENT);
    size_t phdrsz = elf64_fsize(ELF_T_PHDR, 1, EV_CURRENT);
    ehdr->e_entry = LOADADDR + ehdrsz + phdrsz;

    if ((phdr = elf64_newphdr(e, 1)) == NULL)
    {
        errx(EX_SOFTWARE, "elf64_newphdr failed: %s\n", elf_errmsg(-1));
    }

    if ((scn = elf_newscn(e)) == NULL)
    {
        errx(EX_SOFTWARE, "elf_newscn failed: %s\n", elf_errmsg(-1));
    }

    if ((data = elf_newdata(scn)) == NULL)
    {
        errx(EX_SOFTWARE, "elf64_newdata failed: %s\n", elf_errmsg(-1));
    }

    data->d_align = 1;
    data->d_off = 0LL;
    data->d_buf = code;
    data->d_type = ELF_T_BYTE;
    data->d_size = sizeof(code);
    data->d_version = EV_CURRENT;

    if ((shdr = elf64_getshdr(scn)) == NULL)
    {
        errx(EX_SOFTWARE, "elf64_getshdr %s\n", elf_errmsg(-1));
    }

    shdr->sh_name = 1;
    shdr->sh_type = SHT_PROGBITS;
    shdr->sh_flags = SHF_EXECINSTR | SHF_ALLOC;
    shdr->sh_addr = LOADADDR + ehdrsz + phdrsz;

    if (elf_update(e, ELF_C_NULL) < 0)
    {
        errx(EX_SOFTWARE, "elf_update failed: %s\n", elf_errmsg(-1));
    }

    phdr->p_type = PT_LOAD;
    phdr->p_offset = 0;
    phdr->p_filesz = ehdrsz + phdrsz + sizeof(code);
    phdr->p_memsz = phdr->p_filesz;
    phdr->p_vaddr = LOADADDR;
    phdr->p_paddr = phdr->p_vaddr;
    phdr->p_align = 4;
    phdr->p_flags = PF_X | PF_R;

    elf_flagphdr(e, ELF_C_SET, ELF_F_DIRTY);

    if (elf_update(e, ELF_C_WRITE) < 0)
    {
        errx(EX_SOFTWARE, "elf_update failed: %s\n", elf_errmsg(-1));
    }

    elf_end(e);
    close(fd);

    return 0;
}
```

2. Копиляция

   cc ex3.c -o ex3 -g -lelf
3. Выполнение

   ./ex3 test
4. objdump -D test

```
test:     file format elf64-big

objdump: can't disassemble for architecture UNKNOWN!
```

5. hexdump -C test

```c
00000000  7f 45 4c 46 02 02 01 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |.ELF............|
00000010  00 02 00 3e 00 00 00 01  00 00 00 00 08 04 80 78  |...>...........x|
00000020  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 40  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 88  |.......@........|
00000030  00 00 00 00 00 40 00 38  00 01 00 40 00 02 00 00  |.....@.8...@....|
00000040  00 00 00 01 00 00 00 05  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000050  00 00 00 00 08 04 80 00  00 00 00 00 08 04 80 00  |................|
00000060  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 84  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 84  |................|
00000070  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 04  b8 3c 00 00 00 bf 00 00  |.........<......|
00000080  00 00 0f 05 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000090  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
000000c0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 01 00 00 00 01  |................|
000000d0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 06  00 00 00 00 08 04 80 78  |...............x|
000000e0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 78  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 0c  |.......x........|
000000f0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01  |................|
*
00000108
```

6. Выполнение ELF

```c
$ ./test
bash: ./test: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

Answer (score 1):

Код стал работать правильно после приведения полей к следующему виду:

```
    ehdr->e_ident[EI_DATA] = ELFDATA2LSB;
    ehdr->e_ident[EI_CLASS] = ELFCLASS64;
    ehdr->e_machine = EM_X86_64;
```